# Waiting for a number of loaded images before executing script

Tags: javascript

I have a hidden div tag that will be used for a running total of loaded images:

```
<div id="ImagesLoaded">0</div>
```

When an image page runs it loads 8 images, and every `onload` adds 1 to 'ImagesLoaded'. Some images may be bigger than others, so the page load times can vary. When 'ImagesLoaded' is 8 I want to run a script to adjust my screen, which will be based on the sizing and orientation of the images.

What I want to know is this: how can I run a script in the background that checks every 100 milliseconds how many images I have loaded? When there 8 images, it should stop looking at the amount, and run another script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you make such check in `img.onload` handler instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 onLoad = "addOneToImagesLoaded();"
```

and the js:

```
 function addOneToImagesLoaded(){
      current_count = parseInt(getElementById('ImagesLoaded').innerHTML);
      current_count = current_count+1;
      getElementById('ImagesLoaded').innerHTML = current_count.toString();
      if (current_count == 8){
           YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE
      }
 }
```

Comment: Did even occur to me to add it there. Worked great..!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval):

```
var imageInterval = setInterval(checkingFunction, 100);

function checkingFunction()
{
    if (count == 8)
    {
         // do what you want to do
         clearInterval(imageInterval);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could call a function like this in the onload handlers:

```
function imageLoaded()
{
     count++;
     if (count == 8)
     {
         // do what you want to do
     }
}
```

In both examples I'm using a global `count` variable rather than a div element to store the value.